# How to write a text in two textbox control at a time

Tags: jquery

I am working with jquery, i want to write a text in two textbox control at  a time.

Comment: Explain a little bit more perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1" />
<input type="text" id="textbox2" />
```

jQuery

`$('#textbox1, #textbox2').val('some text');`

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1" class="sameclass" />
<input type="text" id="textbox2" class="sameclass" />
```

JS

```
$('input.sameclass').val('some text')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `id^=`

```
$('[id^=textbox]').val('some text');
```